# Displaying data from my .json file in a windows form in C#

Tags: c#, json, datagridview, json.net

I have been reading for the last couple days about this issue and have many similar questions but none have helped me.

I have my data inside my .json file in the following format:

```
{
  "Run from 27.09.2021 19:47:22": {
    "decksize": 52,
    "correctcards": 23,
    "time2mem": "00:00:5434",
    "time2sor": "00:00:4214",
    "mempalaces": [ "none" ],
    "troublecards": [ "none" ]
  }
  ,
  "Run from 27.09.2021 19:47:29": {
    "decksize": 32,
    "correctcards": 1,
    "time2mem": "00:00:5628",
    "time2sor": "00:00:5724",
    "mempalaces": [ "none" ],
    "troublecards": [ "none" ]
  },
  "Run from 27.09.2021 19:47:36": {
    "decksize": 32,
    "correctcards": 11,
    "time2mem": "00:00:6224",
    "time2sor": "00:00:5201",
    "mempalaces": [ "none" ],
    "troublecards": [ "none" ]
  }
}
```

and I want to display it in a datagridview or whatever else is the easiest way (if a listbox is easier then so be it).

I have tried to deserialize it into an object using `Newtonsoft.Json` but I was hoping to find a way using just `System.Text.Json` and `System.Text.Json.Serialization` as these two have worked for me in my project.

I am currently deserializing like this: `data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<values_advanced>(jsonString);` and binding my data source like this: `dbHistory.DataSource = data;` but the grid is just empty when I start my program.

I also tried converting the jsonString into a DataTable like this: `var data2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<values_advanced>>(jsonString);` but I encountered an error claiming that NewtonSoft ran into complications. I pasted the whole error [here](https://pastebin.com/g4i3T3kQ).

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have spent most of my free time on this issue now and it is starting to bug me.

I have included a screenshot from Excel to visualize how I want the data to be visualized:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KoDL.png)

Comment: What does your `values_advanced` class look like? And what does your XAML look like for your DataGridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes: your JSON structure's outer type is equivalent to a Dictionary in C#. You cannot use a Dictionary type as a view's DataSource. You will need to transform your dictionary into an `IEnumerable` and an easy way to do so is via LINQ:

```
Dictionary<string, RunData> dict = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, RunData>>(jsonString);
IEnumerable<RunData> data = dict.Values.ToList();
...
```

After creating `data` you can set your DataGridView's DataSource to that enumerable.

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If it answered your question, consider marking it as the answer to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try this using System.Text.Json

```
var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,Data>>(json).Values.ToList();
```

but you neeed to convert arrays to string in order to use it as data source for Grid View, so

```
List<GvData> dataSource = list.Select(v => new GvData
    {
        Decksize = v.Decksize,
        Correctcards = v.Correctcards,
        Time2Mem = v.Time2Mem,
        Time2Sor = v.Time2Sor,
        Mempalaces = string.Join(",", v.Mempalaces),
        Troublecards = string.Join(",", v.Troublecards)
    }).ToList();
.....

dbHistory.DataSource = dataSource ;
```

classes

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonPropertyName("decksize")]
    public long Decksize { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("correctcards")]
    public long Correctcards { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("time2mem")]
    public string Time2Mem { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("time2sor")]
    public string Time2Sor { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("mempalaces")]
    public string[] Mempalaces { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("troublecards")]
    public string[] Troublecards { get; set; }
}

public partial class GvData
{
    public long Decksize { get; set; }
    public long Correctcards { get; set; }
    public string Time2Mem { get; set; }
    public string Time2Sor { get; set; }
    public string Mempalaces { get; set; }
    public string Troublecards { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help. First, you need a class that describes your format...

```
[Serializable()]
    public class MyRuns
    {
        public string Run_Name { get; set; }
        public int decksize { get; set; }
        public int correctcards { get; set; }
        public string time2mem { get; set; }
        public string time2sor { get; set; }
        public string mempalaces { get; set; }
        public string troublecards { get; set; }
    }
```

```
using System.Text.Json;
```

I had to make a couple of slight changes to your json, but this works...

```
string strJson = @"[{

    ""Run_Name"": ""Run from 27.09.2021 19:47:22"",
    ""decksize"": 52,
    ""correctcards"": 23,
    ""time2mem"": ""00:00:5434"",
    ""time2sor"": ""00:00:4214"",
    ""mempalaces"": ""none"",
    ""troublecards"": ""none""
        },
{
    ""Run_Name"": ""Run from 27.09.2021 19:47:29"",
    ""decksize"": 32,
    ""correctcards"": 1,
    ""time2mem"": ""00:00:5628"",
    ""time2sor"": ""00:00:5724"",
    ""mempalaces"": ""none"",
    ""troublecards"": ""none""
    },
  {
    ""Run_Name"": ""Run from 27.09.2021 19:47:36"",
    ""decksize"": 32,
    ""correctcards"": 11,
    ""time2mem"": ""00:00:6224"",
    ""time2sor"": ""00:00:5201"",
    ""mempalaces"": ""none"",
    ""troublecards"": ""none""
    }
]";

List<MyRuns> myRuns = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyRuns>>(strJson);

            foreach(var r in myRuns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Run Name: " + r.Run_Name);
                Console.WriteLine("decksize: " + r.decksize);
                Console.WriteLine("correctcards: " + r.correctcards.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("time2mem: " + r.time2mem.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("time2sor: " + r.time2sor.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("mempalaces: " + r.mempalaces);
                Console.WriteLine("troublecards: " + r.troublecards);
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
            }
```

Output:

```
--------------------------------------
Run Name: Run from 27.09.2021 19:47:22
decksize: 52
correctcards: 23
time2mem: 00:00:5434
time2sor: 00:00:4214
mempalaces: none
troublecards: none
----------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
Run Name: Run from 27.09.2021 19:47:29
decksize: 32
correctcards: 1
time2mem: 00:00:5628
time2sor: 00:00:5724
mempalaces: none
troublecards: none
----------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
Run Name: Run from 27.09.2021 19:47:36
decksize: 32
correctcards: 11
time2mem: 00:00:6224
time2sor: 00:00:5201
mempalaces: none
troublecards: none
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the effort!!

Comment: You have a bug in your code    public string mempalaces { get; set; }  should be  public string[] mempalaces { get; set; }

Comment: Ah, the example wasn't clear that it was an array. I see.